# Cordova iOS Filetransfer download file into www folder

Tags: ios, file, download, cordova

I'm doing an IOS app with Cordova/phonegap and i have to download an XML file from a remote server, at the success event i need to override the already existing XML file inside the www folder with the just downloaded one.
Any suggestion in how to?

Comment: AFAIK that is not possible. You can only download the app's "document" folder

Comment: Mmmm so wich Is the path i have to use in my ajax get method to rich the file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update a file included in your app package. This would require an updated version of your app to be installed.

However, you can have an external directory host some dynamic data elsewhere on the device disk. You could have some default offline data included in your package, which could be updated by downloading content in this spare directory when the app gets online.

Here is an exemple of Cordova download FileTransfer for iOS:
http://mythoughtsandexperiments.blogspot.fr/2013/10/phonegap-file-downloading-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the `download` method of the `FileTransfer` object described here http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer